# É possível melhorar essa parte do codigo?

Tags: java, android, if

Estou precisando melhorar uma parte do código.

Meu problema é que está muito repetitivo esse `if` e `else`, o ruim é que terei mais coisas repetitivas por conta que são diferentes jogos.

Consigo melhorar essa parte do código por algo mais legível ou até mesmo menor?

```
public Double valuesGames(String game){
    if (game.equals(constantes.getGameDiadeSorte())){
        //Valores referente a Dia de Sorte
        if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 7){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte();
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 8){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 3;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 9){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 4;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 10){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 5;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 11){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 6;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 12){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 7;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 13){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 10;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 14){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 11;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 15){
            value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + 15;
        }
    } else if (game.equals(constantes.getGameQuina())){
        //Valores referente a QUINA
        if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 5){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina();
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 6){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 3;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 7){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 4;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 8){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 5;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 9){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 6;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 10){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 7;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 11){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 8;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 12){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 9;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 13){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 10;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 14){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 11;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 15){
            value = constantes.getAmountQuina() * 12;
        }
    }else if (game.equals(constantes.getGameMega())){
        //Valores referente a MEGA-SENA
        if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 6){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega();
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 7){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 3;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 8){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 4;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 9){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 5;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 10){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 6;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 11){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 7;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 12){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 8;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 13){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 9;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 14){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 10;
        }else if (getNumbersBalls().size() == 15){
            value = constantes.getAmountMega() * 11;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Sim e muito, tanto na estrutura quanto na lógica.

Comment: você consegue me da uma luz de como fazer essa alteração ?

Comment: Uma das coisas que vc pode fazer é chamar essas funções getAmount somente uma vez e depois tratar o resultado dela. Mesma coisa p função get number balls

Comment: @Edi você também pode substituir os `else ifs` por um `switch case`.

Comment: @William isto não diminuiria a repetição.

Comment: Um jogo não poderia ser uma classe base onde cada tipo de jogo a implementasse e tivesse seu próprio 'valuesGames()'? Isso diminuiria o código dentro de uma única função. Seriam 3 classes: uma para Dia da sorte, outro Quina e outro Mega sena

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode trocar performance por código mais enxuto. Existe um padrão aí e você pode generalizar tudo o que está neste padrão. Se fosse um padrão totalmente regular poderia resolver com matemática simples, mas existe uma exceção que é a primeira verificação e os valores que são usados para somar ou multiplicar precisam constar em uma tabela. Confira se eu não comi bola em alguma coisa ou se o código original não tem problemas, por exemplo o que deveria fazer se o número for maior que estes verificados. Reforço que isto ficará mais lento, não muito, mas ficará:

```
int[] somadoresDiaDeSorte = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 15 };
int[] multiplicadoresQuina = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
int[] multiplicadoresMega = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
if (game.equals(constantes.getGameDiadeSorte())) {
    if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 7) value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte();
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < i < multiplicadoresDiaDeSorte.length; i++) {
            if (getNumbersBalls().size() == i + 8) {
                value = constantes.getAmountDiaDeSorte() + somadoresDiaDeSorte[i];
                break;
        }
    }
}
if (game.equals(constantes.getGameQuina())) {
    if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 5) value = constantes.getAmountQuina();
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < i < multiplicadoresQuina.length; i++) {
            if (getNumbersBalls().size() == i + 6) {
                value = constantes.getAmountQuina() + multiplicadoresQuina[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (game.equals(constantes.getGameMega())) {
    if (getNumbersBalls().size() <= 6) value = constantes.getAmountMega();
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < i < multiplicadoresMega.length; i++) {
            if (getNumbersBalls().size() == i + 7) {
                value = constantes.getAmountMega() + multiplicadoresMega[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/LoopIfs.java).

Dá pra generalizar um pouco mais e fazer com que os três virem um só, mas acho que começa parametrizar demais para códigos normais. Precisaria ter um motivo muito forte para fazer isto, envolveria *lambda* (para estabelecer quais os métodos devem ser usados para pegar o dado ser comparado e a quantidade do elementos de cada operação) e só para escrever menos código não acho que fica legal, e tem um número que precisaria ser parametrizado também, mas dei as dicas se quiser fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado, com isso consegui uma redução de 50% de código.